# menu <li> on hover display div with transition

Tags: jquery, html, css

i am trying to display a div when hover on a li (the div have some items but not standard height). but i can't make it.

```
<li>
<a class="testli" id="testli">testli</a>
</li>

<div class="menu" id="menu">
some text
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
$( "#testli" ).hover(function() {
        $("#menu").toggleClass( "menu_show" );
});
}); 

.menu {
background:#fff;
color:#000;
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:0;
color:#000;
z-index:999;
overflow:hidden;
-webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease;
-moz-transition: all 1000ms ease;
-ms-transition: all 1000ms ease;
-o-transition: all 1000ms ease;
transition: all 1000ms ease;
}

.menu_show {    
height:auto;
-webkit-transition: all 1000ms ease;
-moz-transition: all 1000ms ease;
-ms-transition: all 1000ms ease;
-o-transition: all 1000ms ease;
transition: all 1000ms ease;
}
```

is there any way to display the div with jquery(fade in out) with transition? i tried to put height:auto; but it has no transition

Comment: Can you please provide sample HTML as well for questions like this?

Comment: You're using the click function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, change

```
$( "#testli" ).click(function() {
...
```

with:

```
$( "#testli" ).hover(function() {
...
```

then, remove from CSS

```
height:0;
```

Because you can't hover an area with 0 px height. Instead you should set an initial and final height to make transition works correctly. See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/6osvday1/2/)

Comment: i edit my code, i 've been mistaken. is it possible to hover with transition because height: auto; is not working. i dont have standard height in the hover div